# What set of toolkits and frameworks should I learn to be considered as a good tester

Tags: selenium, java, selenium-webdriver

I am very new at testing, so my apologies in advance if my question is very primary.

I started my job as a Tester 4 months ago. I am using Java, Selenium and Sikuli to write tests for applications. I know that my question is very wide but I was wondering what other stuff should I learn to be a better tester?

Is there any package of different tool kits and frameworks that if I learn them I could call myself a good tester?

Again my apologies to ask such a wide question but I am really lost between too many frameworks and tools and ways of testing and need to follow a track.

Comment: Additionally if you want to write decent (effective, reusable etc) automated tests you have to become a decent developer. So, yeah, get cracking on that.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any package of different toolkits and frameworks that if I
>   learn them I could call myself a good tester?

Good testers aren't defined by a magic set of toolkits and frameworks.

Good testers are defined by their ability to test in lots of contexts - automated, manual, etc.

In particular, good testers are good thinkers who can understand the need of the company and the system-under-test and apply their background and knowledge to get the job done in the time given.

Answer (score 2):

You can enhance your java-Testdriver scripts by *datadriven* ability. With such, you can do much more tests with single script. Disadvantage is, you have to think about maintain datasets for different tests. Datadriven testing is followed by technology leaders as Tosca Testsuite.

Another thing you can try with Selenium is mastering Xpath to make better and more robust locators of HTML or whatever you test.

But I do agree with Joe Strazzere, it is too wide question. Nothing (frameworks, methodologies or tools) will assure, you will be better tester.

Answer (score 1):

[Joe](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/68/joe-strazzere) is absolutely correct.

Imagine you have been given a duty to prepare a tea. You have been given a tea pan, and the ingredients to make tea (water,sugar, milk, tea leaves, and some ginger as well ). All these ingredients are from different brands.

Consider the tea as your end product and the ingredients to be the various components which will allow you to integrate and prepare a final product.

Now, when you're preparing tea, your function is to properly mix all the ingredients-irrespective of the brands and prepare a nice, properly cooked tea.

How do you think would your mettle as a cook would be measured?

Would it be measured how good you prepared tea- it's overall quality, or would it be measured on the basis of how you used X brand of tea leaves, mixed with Y brand of sugar, and Z brand of milk.

You should be skilled enough to be not bothered by the brands/make of the ingredients. Instead, you should be skilled enough to know, how these all, in spite of being different, can be mixed and cooked together to prepare a nice hot cup of tea.

The essence of this example, is that instead of being caught up in all the spider web of frameworks and tools, you need to rather hone your all-round skills- skills which rise above the boundaries- of which tool, technology, you use.

Few good reads that would serve the purpose :

http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2013/01/31/becoming-a-world-class-tester/
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/10-qualities-that-can-make-you-a-good-tester/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a greater tester, you need to cultivate a mindset of curiosity and skepticism.  Without that, knowing tools and frameworks is useless.  On the other hand, not knowing tools and frameworks will slow you down.  That knowledge is not sufficient, but it's necessary.

If you expect to read your developers' code, you should learn whatever languages they're using, along with whatever unit-testing framework they use, if they do unit-testing.  You might also want to familiarize yourself with the libraries used to access external systems, e.g. SMTP/IMAP/POP, HTTP, SQL.

Beyond that, you should let your work drive the tools you use.  One of the best uses of automation is to *create test data*, so you should learn tools that allow  you to get data into your systems.  That might mean getting really good at SQL and database management tools, or using Curl in interest ways, or using Python to create big data files.